# Why is the trace of the Riemann curvature tensor useful?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

As I understand it, the Ricci curvature tensor is the trace of the Riemann curvature tensor. In other words, 
\begin{equation}
R_{ij} := R_{kij}^{\phantom{kij}k} = g^{km}R_{kijm}
\end{equation} 
But what information does this give me that the Riemann curvature tensor does not?

EDIT:

Based on comments, perhaps another way of phrasing my question is

what information does the Ricci make clear?

or

what is the meaning of the Ricci tensor?

Comment: If someone knows how to write the tensor index notation properly in Latex, tell me in a comment and I will fix it. I couldn't figure out how. I wanted the superscript $k$ to go to the end but it put it next to the R when I used ^

Comment: I pushed the superscript over using `\phantom{kij}` which inserts the same space as `kij` would but without the ink.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Um, yes but I thought there might be a more direct way to do it instead of \phantom. If not, oh well. Thanks for doing it tho.

Comment: being that the Ricci is constructed from the Riemann, it seems unlikely it has new information, I think your question is really, what information does the Ricci make clear, what is the meaning of the Ricci tensor perhaps?

Comment: @JamesRCook that may be a better way of phrasing it. I will add that as an edit.

Comment: Have you read through Wikipedia's explanation of the [geometric meaning of the Ricci tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Direct_geometric_meaning)? Roughly speaking it explains that $R_{ab}v^av^b$ measures the volume of a small cone around $v$ (or rather, the deviation of this volume from the Euclidean volume). [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119641/geometric-picture-of-scalar-curvature) MO thread also has some nice answers about the difference between Ricci and scalar curvature.

Comment: @mollyerin a nice MO thread. Yeah I read Wikipedia but I didn't really understand it. The MO thread joggled my memory though. I remember reading somewhere about the Ricci tensor being a sort of mean-value or something like that...an average if you will. But I never learned why that property is related to taking the trace of the Riemann curvature tensor. Is there a good book that discuss the Ricci more in depth? The MO thread made it sound like its part of standard curriculum in differential geometry.

Comment: I don't know of any books that discuss the Ricci tensor in particular (in more depth than you'll find in a standard intro textbook). You could of course try books on GR or on Einstein manifolds (but I haven't read any at length). I wrote a bit about the really elementary properties of the Ricci tensor in an answer below, which hopefully clarifies the "Ricci tensor is an average of sectional curvatures" idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few elementary thoughts from a pure Riemannian geometry perspective. ([Muphrid](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45296/muphrid)'s answer gives a nice GR-based perspective, which is obviously a super important application of the Ricci tensor, with which I am much less familiar. I should remark that I don't have much experience with either GR or Einstein manifolds, which is to say I haven't encountered the Ricci tensor much in my life.)

I find the abstract index notation gets in the way of the following explanation a bit, so I'm going to use the following notation: $Ric(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Ricci tensor; if $v, w$ are tangent vectors at a point $p \in M$, (which would be written in abstract index notation as $v^a, w^a$), then
$$
   Ric(v, w) = R_{ab} v^a w^b.
$$ 
$Ric$ is symmetric, so one way of thinking about $Ric$ is just to try and interpret $Ric(v,v)$ for all tangent vectors $v$ (since this determines $Ric$ in general), and it suffices then to just try to understand this when $||v|| = 1$.

By definition $Ric$ is the trace of the Riemann curvature tensor on its first and last indices. If $v \in T_pM$ choose an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ for $T_pM$ with $e_1 = v$; then
$$
  Ric(v, v) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \langle R(e_i,v)v, e_i \rangle.
$$
(If you are only familiar with the abstract index notation, the thing on the right is given by
$$
  \langle R(v, w) x, y \rangle = g_{\tau d} R_{abc}^{\phantom{abc}\tau} v^a w^b x^c y^d, 
$$
but I think this gets pretty hard to read with the subscripts $e_i$ sitting around as well.)

Anyway the point is that, when $e_i, v$ are orthonormal, $\langle R(e_i, v)v, e_i \rangle$ gives the sectional curvature of the plane spanned by $e_i$ and $v$. In particular,
$$
  \frac{1}{n-1} Ric(v, v),
$$ 
when $||v|| = 1$, is an average of the sectional curvatures of 2-planes through $v$. (This same argument is given at the end of Chapter 8 of [Lee's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387983228), which I infer might be what you're using since your equation for the Ricci tensor agrees to the letter with the definition on page 124.)

In particular, the condition that $\tfrac{1}{n-1}Ric(v, v) \geq \lambda$ for all unit vectors $v$ is a weaker version of the condition that all sectional curvatures are bounded below by $\lambda$, and similarly for other inequalities; one can think of it as a hypothesis on "average" sectional curvatures starting from $v$.

Among results that use Ricci curvature bounds in their hypotheses, the [Bonnet-Myers theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem) is a particularly famous one (Theorem 11.8 in Lee). The assumption in that theorem is that when $||v|| = 1$ the Ricci tensor satisfies
$$
   \frac{1}{n-1} Ric(v, v) \geq \frac{1}{R^2},
$$
which we can now read as saying that for each $v$, the "average" sectional curvature of planes through $v$ is bounded below by $1/R^2$. This is the sectional curvature of a sphere of radius $R$, and so it's appropriate that the conclusion of the theorem is that such a manifold is compact and has diameter less than $\pi R$ (which is the diameter of such a sphere -- "diameter" meaning now the greatest distance between two of its points).

I also am partial to the "Ricci curvature measures the second-order deviation in the volume of small cones" given [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Direct_geometric_meaning) as a nice "picture" to keep in my head, but if the proof on Wikipedia doesn't seem to make sense to you, I wouldn't worry about it. (In particular, don't worry about it until you have a strong grasp of Jacobi fields.)

Comment: Are Jacobi fields important? What I mean is, they don't show up in my elementary GR texts but they do in my differential geometry ones and I can't figure out if they are useful to study.

Comment: In my opinion they're the most important tool in Riemannian geometry. But I don't do GR, so if that's what you're interested in, I don't know. (Of course, they're variation fields associated to families of geodesics, and so, for instance, they're implicit in the discussion of the "geodesic deviation equation" on pp. 46-47 of [Wald](http://www.amazon.com/General-Relativity-Robert-M-Wald/dp/0226870332), which is the only elementary GR text I have...)

Comment: First Sentence of Wikipedia definition: "In Riemannian geometry, a Jacobi field is a vector field a long a geodesic $\gamma$ in a Riemannian manifold describing the difference between the geodesic and an "infinitesimally close" geodesic." If that's what it is, then Misner, Thorne and Wheeler may allude to this in their text *Gravitation*. They keep talking about a separation vector $\xi$ used to measure deviation between neighboring geodesics. That sounds very much like the definition I just repeated off Wikipedia. In other words they maybe using a similar concept but just not under that name.

Comment: Regarding this comment: "I also am partial to the "Ricci curvature measures the second-order deviation in the volume of small cones" given on Wikipedia as a nice "picture" to keep in my head," i am just confused by where the cone comes from. What cone? I haven't seem cones discussed anywhere I've read.

Comment: @StanShunpike If you take the formula ([on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Direct_geometric_meaning)) for the measure in coordinates 
$$
  d\mu_g = (1 - \frac{1}{6}R_{ij}x^ix^j + O(|x|^3))d\mu_{\text{Euclidean}}
$$
you can use this to approximately calculate the volume of a small cone around, say, the $x^1$-axis.

Comment: @StanShunpike For instance, when the dimension is $2$, and you take a circular wedge of radius $\epsilon$ and total angle $\eta$, I found (integrate in polar coordinates) that the volume of this wedge is
$$
  \eta \Big(\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} - \frac{1}{24}R_{11} \epsilon^4 \Big) + O(\eta^2\epsilon^2, \epsilon^5),
$$
so the lowest-order deviation from the Euclidean answer $\eta\epsilon^2/2$ is determined by $R_{11}$. (I don't guarantee that I didn't make a mistake in calculation though!)

Comment: Wow! I will have to think about this. I've never tried anything like this before. Interesting!

Answer (score 4):

In general relativity, the Ricci tensor contains all the information necessary to characterize matter's effect on curvature.  This comes directly from the Einstein equation:

$$R_{ab} + \frac{1}{2} R g_{ab} = 8\pi T_{ab}$$

where $T_{ab}$ is the stress-energy tensor, containing all the information about the density, momentum, pressure, and shear of matter.

Perhaps a better question is this: what information is discarded in the Ricci tensor compared to the Riemann?  The answer is the Weyl tensor, which in GR contains information about gravitational waves and tidal deformations.  More broadly, the Weyl tensor can be thought of as describing curvature from sources outside the given point, while the Ricci tensor describes curvature originating from the energy, pressure, momentum, and shear stress of matter at the given point.

From a pure mathematics standpoint, I'm not sure why such a decomposition would be useful, but from a physics standpoint, the different roles the Ricci and Weyl tensors play are quite clear.

Comment: Can you elaborate (or preferably point me to a source) on this difference between Weyl being outside the point and Ricci being at the point?

Comment: That is merely my own interpretation of the notion that the Ricci tensor is zero outside a matter distribution, but the Weyl tensor need not be. One could compare with electromagnetism problems: the Weyl tensor would be compared to the divergence- and curl-free part of the electric field, which is contributed by some exterior source, while the Ricci tensor is similar to the divergence-full part that comes from the charge density in the region of interest.